# Inversion of a block diagonal matrix

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix composed by different blocks. Something similar to a block diagonal matrix of this kind:

```
library(Matrix)    
listElems <- list(matrix(1:4,ncol=2,nrow=2),
                  matrix(5:8,ncol=2,nrow=2),
                  matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),ncol=3,nrow=3),
                  matrix(1:1,ncol=1, nrow=1),
                  matrix(0,ncol=1, nrow=1),
                  matrix(0,ncol=1, nrow=1))
mat <- bdiag(listElems)
mat <- bdiag(mat,mat)
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
```

One way to invert this matrix is to invert its blocks.

I want to use this property and: i) identify the 12 blocks in the matrix, ii) invert them and iii) generate the inverted matrix.

What I was able to do is to identify the blocks and invert them

```
library(igraph)
x <- mat
diag(x) <- 1
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjmatrix = as.matrix(x), mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
groups <- Map(sort, neighborhood(g, nrow(mat)))
groups <- unique(Map(as.numeric, groups))
sub.Mat <- Map(`[`, list(mat), groups, groups, drop = FALSE)
inv.sub.Mat <- Map(ginv,sub.Mat)
```

What I should do now is to create the inverted matrix. To this purpose, the only thing I was able to come up with is to use a loop:

```
n.blocks <- length(inv.sub.Mat) 

mat.inv <- matrix(0,nrow(mat),ncol(mat))
for(i in 1:n.blocks){
  mat.inv[groups[[i]],groups[[i]]] <- inv.sub.Mat[[i]]
}

all.equal(mat.inv,ginv(mat))
```

However, since I have to apply this process iteratively on large scale matrices, I am afraid that this last operation might be not the most efficient way to generate the inverted matrix.

Note that I will not be using exclusively block diagonal matrices, so I cannot simply apply `bdiag` to `inv.sub.Mat`, because I will be changing the order of rows and columns.

Any suggestion to perform this process more efficiently?

Comment: There's `do.call(magic::adiag, inv.sub.Mat)` if you want a "prettier" method, but since you already have `groups` the loop will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you. As I stressed, not always I will work with block diagonal matrices, so `adiag` will not work. I am wondering if I can find a way to use `groups` to assign the values in `inv.sub.Mat` in just one line.